# Previously working version of Ubuntu now boots to black screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I forgot to close my laptop or lock the screen before I went to work the other day, and when I came home my laptop was stuck on a black screen. I should also mention I have a cat who loves to walk and sit on my keyboard and I feel like she was probably the cause of this(I left bash open). I can get to grub when I restart, but if I try to boot with Ubuntu I just get the black screen again. I can't access the login page. I also have Windows 8.1 installed and I can boot that with no problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Edit: I think it may be an issue with my drivers for my graphics card. I have an AMD Radeon HD 8510G. I haven't been able to bypass the black screen to update my drivers though. There was another post about this but the instructions weren't working for me. I tried changing quiet splash to nomodeset and radeon.modeset=0 but I still get the black screen when I boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try Grub Rescue and type this:
`ls`
(then select the portion that has Grub Installed)
`ls (Portion name)
set root=(Partion name)
set prefix=(partion name)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal`
I recommend writing this down because until your computer updates this will continue to happen so I recommend updating ASAP

Comment: Sorry, I'm still pretty new to Linux/Ubuntu. How do you get to Grub Rescue? Also, once I'm there I'm not sure if I'll know what to put for the portion and partition names.

Comment: Is there no option to go to grub rescue? If not then what I thought was wrong also I accidentally spelled Partion sorry. I have never seen a problem like this so I'm sorry I couldn't help